# PHPWord - Can I concatenate multiple font styles in one table cell?

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to write a table in PHPWord that has multiple text formats in one cell for example in HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><b>L</b><sub>1</sub> = 999</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Blah</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I would write it something like this:

```
$table = $section->addTable('myOwnTableStyle');

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(5000)->addText("HOW WOULD I STRING MULTIPLE TEXT FORMATS IN HERE WITH BOLD AND SUBSCRIPTS IN THIS CELL?  IS THERE A CONCATENATE?");
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(5000)->addText("Blah");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $table -> addRow();
 $table -> addCell() -> addText("normal text"); 
 $cell = $table -> addCell();
 $cellRun = $cell->addTextRun($style); 
 $cellRun -> addText("one ");
 $cellRun -> addText("text concat");
```

[Here you can find](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_09_Tables.php) the documentation with an example

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can define a variable as separate parts of the text; unfortunately I can't test this so I will leave it to you to try it out.

```
$boldFont = array('bold'=>true);
$largeFont = array('size'=>28);
$table->addRow();
$myCell1 = $table->addCell(5000);
$myCell1->addText("This is bold text", $boldFont);
$myCell1->addText(", this is large text", $largeFont);
```

See here for some ideas [DOCUMENTATION](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  I was using PHPWord .62 but if you update to PHPWord .11.1 you can use the textrun function to put things into cells the proper way.  .62 has a textrun function but it doesn't appear you can insert into a table cell.